# is there a way to get a push key for the current user?

Tags: java, android, firebase, key, registration

is there a way to get a push key for the current user?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8U82.png)FirebaseUser firebaseuser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); this way we get the current user is there a connection between these data?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYpap.png)

Comment: Do you mean [getting the `.key` property of a `push()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data%23:~:text%3DThe%2520push()%2520method%2520generates,same%2520time%2520without%2520write%2520conflicts.&ved=2ahUKEwjs5tP_vr71AhVNSzABHWw8BpcQFnoECAQQBQ&usg=AOvVaw1tFcXx7W0IR1J1ChneDLgx)?

Comment: What exactly would you like to get from the existing data?